# fill an incomplete correlation matrix in long format with R

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation, tidyr

I have a incomplete square matrix in long format that I would like to fill to use with ggplot2::geom_raster. Let's imagine that this is a correlation matrix with values (z) ranging, here, from 0 to 1.

```
df <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:3], y=LETTERS[c(3,1,2)], z=c(0,1,-1))
df
```

The output is

```
  x y  z
1 A C  0
2 B A  1
3 C B -1
```

I can complete it:

```
library(tidyr)
complete(df,x , y, fill=list(z=NA))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
       x      y     z
  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
1      A      A    NA
2      A      B    NA
3      A      C     0
4      B      A     1
5      B      B    NA
6      B      C    NA
7      C      A    NA
8      C      B    -1
9      C      C    NA
```

Now, as it is supposed to be a correlation matrix, I would like to fill it such that if I know cor(D,A) then I should end up with cor(A,D) == cor(D,A). The expected result would thus be:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
       x      y     z
  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
1      A      A    NA
2      A      B    1
3      A      C     0
4      B      A     1
5      B      B    NA
6      B      C    -1
7      C      A    0
8      C      B    -1
9      C      C    NA
```

I can do complicated stuffs but maybe there is a straightforward solution...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `tidyverse`. Notice that I changed all the factor columns to character before the operation. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  complete(x, y) %>%
  mutate(Group = map2_chr(x, y, ~paste0(sort(c(.x, .y)), collapse = "_"))) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(z = mean(z, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Group)
df2
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   x     y         z
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 A     A       NaN
# 2 A     B         1
# 3 A     C         0
# 4 B     A         1
# 5 B     B       NaN
# 6 B     C        -1
# 7 C     A         0
# 8 C     B        -1
# 9 C     C       NaN
```

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:3], y=LETTERS[c(3,1,2)], z=c(0,1,-1),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot www for the contribution. I was hopping something more readable. But that's a nice workaround.

Comment: I can find the map2_chr function. Did you mean map2 ?

Comment: @user451460 `map2_chr` should be from the `purrr` package, which is part of the `tidyverse` package.

Comment: Sorry, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

I have a data.table solution, using a different technique.

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- complete(df,x , y, fill=list(z=NA))
df2 <- setDT(df2)

df2[!is.na(z),.(x = y, y = x, z = z)][df2,  on = .(x,y)][is.na(z),z:=i.z][,i.z := NULL][]

   x y  z
1: A A NA
2: A B  1
3: A C  0
4: B A  1
5: B B NA
6: B C -1
7: C A  0
8: C B -1
9: C C NA
```

what it does: it merge df2 with

```
df2[!is.na(z),.(x = y, y = x, z = z)]
   x y  z
1: C A  0
2: A B  1
3: B C -1
```

which is the non correlation value but with x and y switched. The result is

```
   x y  z i.z
1: A A NA  NA
2: A B  1  NA
3: A C NA   0
4: B A NA   1
5: B B NA  NA
6: B C -1  NA
7: C A  0  NA
8: C B NA  -1
9: C C NA  NA
```

I then complete z with the i.z values, and supress i.z column. An other syntax using `merge`:

```
merge(df2[!is.na(z),.(x = y, y = x, z = z)],df2,all.y = T,by = c("x","y"))[,z:=ifelse(is.na(z.x),z.y,z.x)][,c("z.x","z.y"):=NULL][]
```

---

same idea with **dplyr**:

```
library(dplyr)

right_join(df2 %>%
  filter(!is.na(z)) %>%
  rename(x = y, y = x),
  df2, by = c("x","y")) %>%
  mutate(z = ifelse(is.na(z.x),z.y,z.x)) %>%
  select(y,x,z)

  y x  z
1 A A NA
2 B A  1
3 C A  0
4 A B  1
5 B B NA
6 C B -1
7 A C  0
8 B C -1
9 C C NA
```

Comment: Bravo Denis and thanks a lot for this solution around data table. Not that readable too... :)

Comment: Although I found it poorly readable on a first attempt, the syntax looks rather explicit after a second pass

Comment: @user451460 Happy you like it. I don't think your problem has an easy solution. The dplyr syntax is maybe more readable